# object(SimpleXMLElement) access values

Tags: php, xml

Bellow is a $xml resultset. I can access the key "dataset" with $xml['dataset'] but i need to access the key "data" and i can't. Can anyone give me a hand on this?

```
object(SimpleXMLElement)#17 (2) { ["@attributes"]=> array(1) { ["dataset"]=> string(101) "/DATOSRED/NUMERICO/PRODUCTOS/WRF/WRF_ARW_1KM_2D/20160414/wrf_arw_det1km_history_d06_20160414_0000.nc4" } ["point"]=> object(SimpleXMLElement)#18 (1) { ["data"]=> array(9) { [0]=> string(20) "2016-04-14T15:00:00Z" [1]=> string(5) "41.15" [2]=> string(10) "-8.6166667" [3]=> string(17) "289.3196105957031" [4]=> string(3) "0.0" [5]=> string(17) "3.244610071182251" [6]=> string(17) "3.326730728149414" [7]=> string(18) "224.28402709960938" [8]=> string(13) "24111.9921875" } } }
```

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples-basic.php. If there's still a question, pls post your XML and your code as well.

Answer (score 1):

```
object(SimpleXMLElement)#17 (2) { 
    ["@attributes"]=> array(1) {
         ["dataset"]=> string(101) "/DATOSRED/NUMERICO/PRODUCTOS/WRF/WRF_ARW_1KM_2D/20160414/wrf_arw_det1km_history_d06_20160414_0000.nc4"
     }
     ["point"]=> object(SimpleXMLElement)#18 (1) {
         ["data"]=> array(9) {
             [0]=> string(20) "2016-04-14T15:00:00Z"
             [1]=> string(5) "41.15"
             [2]=> string(10) "-8.6166667"
             [3]=> string(17) "289.3196105957031" 
             [4]=> string(3) "0.0"
             [5]=> string(17) "3.244610071182251"
             [6]=> string(17) "3.326730728149414"
             [7]=> string(18) "224.28402709960938"
             [8]=> string(13) "24111.9921875"
        }
    }
 }
```

If you format the onject, you can see that the array data is nested inside the object point. So you need to do

```
$xml->point->data
```

To get the data.

Comment: `$xml` appears to be an object, not an array.  Array notation will not work in that case.  You would need something like `$xml->point->data[X]`.

Comment: using $xml->point->data[8] i get for instance:

object(SimpleXMLElement)#19 (2) { ["@attributes"]=> array(2) { ["name"]=> string(10) "visibility" ["units"]=> string(1) "m" } [0]=> string(14) "24074.95703125" } 

:(

Comment: very strange! if i do "echo $xml->point->data[0]" it outputs the date string.
But if i try to assign it like $date = $xml->point->data[0]; it gives me a object!